# Mapping that works in Vim does not work in Neovim

Tags: key-bindings, neovim

I use Tim Pope's plugin [vim-unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired), and one of the shortcuts that it enables is "bubbling" text (moving a line or a set of lines up/down).

In normal mode, the shortcut for bubbling text down is `]e`, and up is `[e`. In visual mode, those are `]egv` and `[egv`. In my `.vimrc` I map them to `<C-U>` and `<C-I>`, respectively:

```
" bubble single lines
nmap <C-U> ]e
nmap <C-I> [e

" bubble multiple lines
vmap <C-U> ]egv
vmap <C-I> [egv
```

In vim, these mappings work. In neovim, the `<C-U>` mappings work, but the `<C-I>` ones do not. To try to debug this, I ran `:verbose map <C-I>`, and see the output I expect (the same when ran in both vim and neovim):

```
v  <C-I>         [egv
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 319
n  <C-I>         [e
        Last set from ~/.vimrc line 315
```

I tried changing the mapping from `<C-I>` to `<C-T>`, and the behavior was correct.

I'm using iTerm 2 `3.4.15`, and `xterm-256color`. Here are the details from `nvim --version`:

```
NVIM v0.7.0
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.1.0-beta3
Compiled by brew@Monterey
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! I think it's possible that there's a conflict between `<C-I>` and `<Tab>` (they typically generate the same code) and for some reason NeoVim is getting confused about it... Though showing output of the maps seems to indicate that the mappings are good. Does it work if you use something else such as `<C-T>` or `<C-Y>` or `<C-T>` instead? (Just trying to isolate the root cause of the issue.)

Comment: I tried mapping it to `<C-T>` and yes, it works! So that implies that it's something in NeoVim that uses the `<C-I>` mapping?

Comment: I think this might have to do with NeoVim using a standard library for handling the terminal, while traditional Vim might have some hacks and recent additions that make it use newer terminal features (e.g. `modifyOtherKeys` which allows it to differentiate `<C-I>` from `<Tab>`.) You might want to list more details into your question, such as which NeoVim version, which terminal emulator, what's your `echo $TERM` or `:set term?` setting, etc., please [edit] the question to include more details (you might also want to indicate that `<C-T>` works in the question itself.)

Comment: Thanks — edited!